# Unrecognized selector calling factory method in static iOS library

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, static-libraries

currently I'm implementing a static library and everything works fine if I use the code "as is" in a test-app, but if I compile my code to a static library, I get an unrecognized selector, here is my code:

`+ (id)sharedInstance {
    DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK(^{
        return [[self alloc] init];
    });
}`

```
#define DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK(block) \
static dispatch_once_t pred = 0; \
__strong static id _sharedObject = nil; \
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ \
_sharedObject = block(); \
}); \
return _sharedObject; \
```

Calling

```
[ZanoxTrackingEvent sharedInstance]
```

results in

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ZanoxTrackingEvent sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x27ee8'

I'm pretty desperate right now, I tried several Singleton-implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when you have the wrong path in your filesystem. This is what happened in my case.